# Remove-MgDomain_Delete1: Domain deletion attempt failed

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-teams

Remove-MgDomain fails
I'm trying to remove a domain using Remove-MgDomain according to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/remove-mgdomain?view=graph-powershell-1.0&preserve-view=true

I can get my domain using Get-MgDomain -DomainID "mydomain.com", but removing the domain fails with a rather nonsensical error message.

```
Remove-MgDomain -DomainId "mydomain.com"
Remove-MgDomain_Delete1: Domain deletion attempt failed.
```

Is that specific cmdlet bugged, or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an AD user still referencing the domain.
Deleted that user, and the removeMgDomain command worked.

Trying to delete the domain directly in the azure portal gave a much more informative errormessage, which made the problem clear.